# Retain specific component in PCA

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, scikit-learn, pca

I have an numpy array called "data" which has 500 rows and 500 columns. Using PCA from sklearn I can compress this to 500 rows and 15 columns. I believe that in essence I go from 500 axes and 500 points to 15 axes and 500 points. The axes are all orthogonal and explain my data very well.

But I want to know if there's anyway to ensure that one of the 15 axes (that I get after running PCA) is also one of the original 500. That is, can I keep one of the original axes and use PCA (or some-other method) to find the remaining 14?

My code is given below:

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
#data is some 500x500 numpy array
pca = PCA(n_components = 15)
pca_result = pca.fit_transform(data)
#pca_result is a 500x15 numpy array
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply drop the axis you want to keep from the data:

```
mask = np.ones(data.shape[1], dtype=np.bool)
mask[special_axis] = False
data_new = data[:, mask]

pca_transformed = PCA(n_components=14).fit_transform(data_new)
```

This is the same as removing the projection along this feature.
You can then stack the original axis with the PCA result if you like:

```
stacked_result = np.hstack([pca_transformed, data[:, [special_axis]]])
```

Comment: I though of this but the resulting 14 dimensions/axes wont be orthogonal to the original. The problem is then identical to PCA in 14 dimensions and arbitrarily adding in 1 more axes in a random way. Am I wrong?

Comment: They are orthogonal. All the PCA axes will be in the remaining 499 dimensions of your data. This subspace is orthogonal to the 1d subspace of the feature you left out.

Comment: But then can I project the remaining 499 data points onto the axes I left out? With the way you're suggesting the special_axes is not a part of the PCA which means the 499 points cant be projected in that axis. I essentially want to find all the points 'orthogonal' to the special axis, and the ones which are most 'similar' to that axis.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're trying to do is to first do a linear least-squares fit to the axis you want to keep:

```
axis_to_keep = data[:,column_number][:,np.newaxis]
# next line solves axis_to_keep*x = data
x = np.linalg.lstsq(axis_to_keep,data)[0]
```

Then subtract the fit generated using that model from `data`:

```
data_2 = data - np.dot(axis_to_keep,x)
```

at which point you can do your PCA on `data_2` with 14 components. Your forced axis (almost certainly) won't be orthogonal to the others.

Comment: I was hoping for something orthogonal. The only way I can think of to make it orthogonal is to actually double the row and column of the 500x500 data set (its a correlation table). That way the specific row/column is more important and you get a result that ends up being orthogonal, and more-often-than-not includes the row/column as an axis.

Comment: why do you want to do a fit to the axis? The direction is just one of the coordinates.

Comment: yeah but I want to find 2 things: 1) which of the remaining 499 data points are most similar to the axis I've chosen. 2) I want to find which of the 499 data points are 'independent' to the axis/point I've chosen.  I say axis/point because since it's a correlation matrix, the axis I've chosen is also a point.

Comment: What do you mean by similar and independent? You asked for orthogonal, so I gave you orthogonal ;)

Comment: So for example, similar points would be ones on the same axis. Independent ones would be ones in different axes.